# Updating a matplotlib bar graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a bar graph which retrieves its y values from a dict. Instead of showing several graphs with all the different values and me having to close every single one, I need it to update values on the same graph. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 15):

Here is an example of how you can animate a bar plot.
You call `plt.bar` only once, save the return value `rects`, and then call `rect.set_height` to modify the bar plot. 
Calling `fig.canvas.draw()` updates the figure.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def animated_barplot():
    # http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations
    mu, sigma = 100, 15
    N = 4
    x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(N)
    rects = plt.bar(range(N), x,  align = 'center')
    for i in range(50):
        x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(N)
        for rect, h in zip(rects, x):
            rect.set_height(h)
        fig.canvas.draw()

fig = plt.figure()
win = fig.canvas.manager.window
win.after(100, animated_barplot)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What if we need to add new bars to the graph with each update? Also, how does fig.canvas.draw() compare to using FuncAnimation?

Answer (score 5):

I've simplified the above excellent solution to its essentials, with more details at my [blogpost](http://www.stochasticdreams.com/2016/08/28/animated-histogram-python/):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numBins = 100
numEvents = 100000

file = 'datafile_100bins_100000events.histogram'
histogramSeries = np.loadtext(file)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects = ax.bar(range(numBins), np.ones(numBins)*40)  # 40 is upper bound of y-axis 

for i in range(numEvents):
    for rect,h in zip(rects,histogramSeries[i,:]):
        rect.set_height(h)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(0.001)
```

Comment: @stochastic Have you got around to saving the animation?

Comment: @László I cheat and take a desktop video as I don't need high quality.