# How to animate a bar char being updated in Python

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I want to create an animated, stacked bar chart.

There is a [great tutorial](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/), which shows how to animate line graphs.

However, for animating bar charts, the BarContainer object, does not have any attribute to 'set_data'. I am therefore forced to clear the figure axes each time, e.g. ,

```
fig=plt.figure()

def init():
    plt.cla()

def animate(i):

    p1 = plt.bar(x_points,y_heights,width,color='b')

return p1


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,init_func=init,frames=400,interval=10,blit=False)
```

Is there an alternative option, following the style of the link, such that I do not have to clear the axes each time? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to call `plt.bar` outside of `animation()`, update the height of each bar with `Rectangle.set_height` as new data comes in.

In practice, loop through each incoming set of y_heights zipped with the list of Rectangles returned by plt.bar() as seen below.

```
p1 = plt.bar(x_points,y_heights,width,color='b')

def animate(i):
    for rect, y in zip(p1, y_heights):
        rect.set_height(y)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,init_func=init,frames=400,interval=10,blit=False)
```

You might want to put `p1` in your `init()` but that's up to you!

All credit for this answer goes to unutbu's answer in the related question [Updating a matplotlib bar graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489669/updating-a-matplotlib-bar-graph/9489768#9489768?newreg=555c1e2dc08645d595b77b21b14db7f5). I would've added in a comment but I'm obviously quite new.

Answer (score 0):

`plt.bar` returns a list of Rectangles. The length of the list is equal to the number of bars. If you wanted to change the height of say the first bar, you can do `p1[0].set_height(new_height)` and similarly for `width` and a bunch of other Rectangle properties.

As noted [here](https://brushingupscience.wordpress.com/2016/06/21/matplotlib-animations-the-easy-way/#more-2159), the output of `[x for x in dir(p1[0]) if 'set_' in x]` will give you all the potential properties you can set.